# Kitten being weird, could it be rabies?

Tags: cats, health

I have a kitten (born May 7 2014) now for almost 3 months. Usually, during the evening, he has a good appetite and runs around. 
Today, afternoon he has been sleepy all the time, very calm, folds his paws and lies looking around, and doesn't react to food. He also feels very warm.

Could it be symptoms of rabies? He is a deaf kitty so he's always inside the house. Also, there's a chance he got hit on his head today when he was playing under the bed and the board accidentally fell on him :(

Comment: Has he had the rabies vaccine?

Answer (score 6):

No, this doesn't look like rabies to be honest. Rabies symptoms typically include:

- Attitude changes
- Erratic behaviour - weird biting, odd wandering, tends to be excitable and/or irritable, or shows signs of viciousness
- Disoriented
- Loss of coordination, paralysis
- Excessive salivation

Either way, there's clearly some reason for you to be concerned (head injury) and so I would get him to the vet for a check up. Also consider other environmental factors such as heat and so forth. Cats are generally not that active (in fact they sleep about two thirds of their lives) and heat can make them less so.